# XPath expression to select all child elements that are not some specific element

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given the XML

```
<blockquote>
    <attribution>foo</attribution>
    <para>bar</para>
</blockquote>
```

I have the XSL template

```
<xsl:template match="dbk:blockquote">
    <blockquote>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(dbk:attribution)]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dbk:attribution" />
    </blockquote>
</xsl:template>
```

where the first `apply-templates` should select all child elements of the `dbk:blockquote` that are not of type `dbk:attribution`.  (This is necessary to move attributions to the bottom.)

However, it in fact matches every node.  Why?

Comment: _"Type"_ has an specific meaning in XML Schema/XPath world...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `self` axis:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::dbk:attribution)]" />
```

This selects child elements that are not *themselves* a `dbk:attribution` element. Your version selects child elements that do not *contain* a `dbk:attribution` child.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, that works.  (And the reason mine doesn't makes sense, too.)

Answer (score 0):

I am no xpath expert. But I think this should work.

```
<xsl:template match="dbk:blockquote">
    <blockquote>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name(.) != 'attribution']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name(.) = 'attribution']" />
    </blockquote>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: How strange.  There's seriously no shortcut for this?  I'd say it's the simplest possible example of `not()`, yet examples cover more complex stuff like `author[degree and not(publication)]` which is shorter than this.  Also, when I add the namespace (i.e. `attribution` becomes `dbk:attribution`) the first matches the `attribution` element and the second matches the `para` element!  That's certainly weird.